# How can I install another Operating System through MAAS?

Tags: maas

I want to install CentOS and Microsoft Windows Server 2008 using MAAS. How can it be achieved? I have already installed MAAS server on a single machine.

Comment: This is about Ubuntu how?

Comment: @WarrenHill Actually, this is related to Ubuntu. [MAAS](https://maas.ubuntu.com/) is something provided by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

In version 1.7 MAAS supports Windows, Centos and SuSE.

[Changelog](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.7/changelog.html#id2)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, Only Ubuntu is currently supported.

Comment: Can you provide some links to official sources which state this fact? Are there plans to support other Operating Systems in future?

Comment: Maybe this will help you : http://askubuntu.com/questions/267700/limitations-of-ubuntu-cloud-infrastructure-with-respect-to-os